# How to run a postinstall script when publishing angular4 app to azure website using kuduscript?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, angular-cli, azure-cli

I have an angular4 app that is deployed to azure web app (website) by configuring Deployment Options via Portal.
I used kuduscript to create custom deployment script [`kuduscript -y –node`] and then edited `deploy.cmd` to tell azure how to run angular app.

Dependencies were adjusted in `package.json`. The prod build [`ng build --prod`] runs fine locally, but creates an error in azure:

> Failed at the ng2project@0.0.2 postinstall script 'node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update'
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'D:\home\site\repository\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager' at Function.Module._resolveFilename ....

This is because of the `postinstall` under `scripts` in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "modernizr": "modernizr -c modernizr-config.json -d src/modernizr.js",
  "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

If I remove it, build works fine. I suspect its because the files are transferred to `wwwroot` folder from `respository` folder before `postinstall` gets called. Looking for pointers on how to fix this.

This is the modified `deploy.cmd` in use:

```
    @if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off
    :: ----------------------
    :: KUDU Deployment Script
    :: Version: 1.0.15
    :: ----------------------

    :: Prerequisites
    :: -------------

    :: Verify node.js installed
    where node 2>nul >nul
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
      echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
      goto error
    )

    :: Setup
    :: -----

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

    IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
      SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
    )

    IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
      SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
    )

    IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
      SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

      IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
        SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
      )
    )

    IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
      :: Install kudu sync
      echo Installing Kudu Sync
      call npm install kudusync -g --silent
      IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

      :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
      SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
    )
    goto Deployment

    :: Utility Functions
    :: -----------------

    :SelectNodeVersion

    IF DEFINED KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD (
      :: The following are done only on Windows Azure Websites environment
      call %KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
      IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

      IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp" (
        SET /p NODE_EXE=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp"
        IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
      )
      
      IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp" (
        SET /p NPM_JS_PATH=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp"
        IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
      )

      IF NOT DEFINED NODE_EXE (
        SET NODE_EXE=node
      )

      SET NPM_CMD="!NODE_EXE!" "!NPM_JS_PATH!"
    ) ELSE (
      SET NPM_CMD=npm
      SET NODE_EXE=node
    )

    goto :EOF

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: Deployment
    :: ----------

    :Deployment
    echo Handling node.js deployment.

    :: 1. Select node version
    call :SelectNodeVersion

    :: 2. Install npm packages
    IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\package.json" (
      pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
      call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
      IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
      popd
    )

    :: 3. Angular Prod Build
    IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%/.angular-cli.json" (
    echo Building App in %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%…
    pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
    call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! run build
    :: If the above command fails comment above and uncomment below one
    :: call ./node_modules/.bin/ng build –prod
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
    popd
    )

    :: 4. KuduSync
    IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
      call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%/dist" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
      IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
    )
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    goto end

    :: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
    :ExecuteCmd
    setlocal
    set _CMD_=%*
    call %_CMD_%
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
    exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

    :error
    endlocal
    echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
    call :exitSetErrorLevel
    call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

    :exitSetErrorLevel
    exit /b 1

    :exitFromFunction
    ()

    :end
    endlocal
    echo Finished successfully.
```

Full `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ng2project",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MPL-2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "modernizr": "modernizr -c modernizr-config.json -d src/modernizr.js",
    "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "napa": {
    "jquery.flot.spline": "miloszfalinski/jquery.flot.spline",
    "ika.jvectormap": "kakirigi/ika.jvectormap",
    "flot": "flot/flot#v0.8.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "7.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "1.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.60",
    "ag-grid": "12.0.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "12.0.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "3.9.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.3",
    "angular2-toaster": "^4.0.1",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "2.6.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "codemirror": "5.28.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.4.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jqcloud2": "2.0.3",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "2.4.0",
    "jquery.browser": "0.1.0",
    "jquery.flot.tooltip": "github:krzysu/flot.tooltip",
    "loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "modernizr": "3.5.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-device-detector": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-dnd": "4.2.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "0.9.0",
    "ng2-select": "1.2.0",
    "ng2-table": "1.3.2",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.8.1",
    "ngx-chips": "1.5.3",
    "ngx-color-picker": "4.2.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "screenfull": "3.3.1",
    "simple-line-icons": "2.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
    "spinkit": "1.2.5",
    "summernote": "0.8.6",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.3",
    "weather-icons": "github:erikflowers/weather-icons",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.3.3",
    "@types/codemirror": "0.0.43",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.71",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-read-json": "1.1.0",
    "loaders.css": "0.1.2",
    "napa": "3.0.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.2.0",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

References:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your `package.json` file?

Comment: @AaronChen: Added full package.json for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `protractor` module is listed in **devDependencies**, and you were running the `npm install` with `--production` flag, npm will not install modules listed in **devDependencies**.

So, to avoid this error, you basically have two options:

1. Move `"protractor": "5.1.2",` from **devDependencies** section to **dependencies** section.
2. Edit `deploy.cmd` script to remove `--production` in step 2:

   ```
   :: 2. Install npm packages
   IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\package.json" (
     pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
     call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install
     IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
     popd
   )
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I had moved cli, types/node, etc. to dependencies, but missed protractor. Cheers!